# Numpy's dot product not associative

Tags: numpy

Computing the `dot` product in the following three cases produce different results for my specific set of complex NumPy arrays, but not for a second set of random matrices which have the same sizes and data ranges.

```
a.dot(b).dot(c).dot(d)
a.dot(b.dot(c).dot(d))
a.dot(b.dot(c)).dot(d)
```

produces

```
[[  2.23903250e-08 -1.29444679e-07j]]
[[  6.09565057e-07 +2.09702260e-07j]]
[[  3.40257465e-07 -1.20382176e-07j]]
```

The arrays are quite large with one having around 14 mio. entries. Could the size be an issue? If so, why does numpy not raise a warining?

Comment: I would upload the arrays as `.npz`, but the file is ~ 200 mb large

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to rounding error, these results are identical - they're all zero matrices. Differences in rounding error are normal.

Comment: Ok, see the problem. In the acousitcs domain, 10^-7 is sometimes not zero. I was not comparing these results with the magnitude of the values in the arrays.

Comment: But why do these caculations give exactly the same result for random arrays of the same size with equivalent value ranges?

Comment: @fhchl: Most likely, they don't, and they just look like they do because the rounding error is much smaller than the output values.

Comment: they are numerically the same if i compare using `==`